# Visual Studio Code autocomplete element and closing tag

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I know on some environment I had Visual Studio Code offered me the following:

- when I start typing element name (HTML element name in HTML file and React element name or React component name in javascript file), like `<di`, vscode offered me to autocomplete it with tab.
- when I press tab it autocompletes it like `<div|`
- now if I press another tab it autocompletes the `<div>|`
- and another tab it makes the `<div>|</div>` with the cursor in the middle

(possibly the third and fourth bullets are single step).

But now I cannot find how to achieve this (I have latest vscode v.1.19). Is it some kind of extension that was doing this or what?

Comment: When I type `di` in a `.html` file and press Tab, it's auto-completed straight to `<div>|</div>`. Is this different from the behavior you're seeing? https://i.imgur.com/6QcamkU.gifv

Comment: Hi. Actually when I inspect now (maybe I'm on a different PC) it works ok, same as you shown, in an .html file. What I probably wanted is that this autocomplete works in a JSX code (react) of .js files. That doesn't work.

Comment: Btw how you made that nice gif?

Comment: ShareX. :) https://getsharex.com/